# Data from Mathematica import to Python

Tags: python, import, wolfram-mathematica

I have a text file containing 3 dimensional array(100X100X100) obtained from Mathematica. The data are stored with commas and curly braces.I want to use this text file to analyse and plot the data using Python. How can I import the data in Python? I am currently using Python 2.7 version. What may be the format to store the data in matematica in order to use it in Python?

Comment: See [this discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4643/how-to-use-mathematica-functions-in-python-programs), for example.

Comment: You might want to consider Pandas. http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: It would depend on how the text file is structured of course.  How did you `Export` it?  If you have a native mathematica format (commas and  curly braces delimited Id suggest first choosing a more friendly format )

Comment: It is stored in native format what you have mentioned. What is the convenient format ?

Answer (score 2):

since it pains me to see folks storing so much data in ascii, here is a way to do a binary exchange:

mathematica:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 4, 5}]
f = OpenWrite["test.bin", BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite[f, ArrayDepth[data], "Integer32"];
BinaryWrite[f, Dimensions[data], "Integer32"];
BinaryWrite[f, data, "Real64"];
Close[f]
```

python:

```
import numpy as np
with open('test.bin','rb') as f:
 depth=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('int32'),count=1)
 dims =np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('int32'),count=depth)
 data =np.reshape(np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('float64'),
         count=reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,dims)),dims)
```

note you can have endian-ness issues if you read/write on different hardware.
( easily handled though )

Edit: for completeness a text exchange using native mathematica format looks like this:

mathematica:

```
m = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {8, 8}]
m >> out.m
```

python:

```
with open('out.m','r') as f: text=f.read()
for rep in (('{','['),('}',']')):text=text.replace(rep[0],rep[1])
array=eval(text)
```

with a couple notes of caution, first `eval` should not be used on untrused input, secondly this will break if any values use scientific notation, or obviously any  mathematica symbolic content. Finally it will undoubtedly be painfully slow for large input.  I would seriously only use this if you are stuck with a mathematica file and can not use mathematica to put it to a better format.