# Read Mathematica generated text file

Tags: python, text, wolfram-mathematica

I have a text file generated by mathematica. I want to convert the text file python readable.The main problem is that the file stores the array with curly bracket("{......}"). Another problem is that mathematica uses I as an imaginary number where as python uses j. What is the solution?

Comment: asking the same question again. ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/44173958/1004168  . You should explain clearly why you want to use that arcane format instead of literally a dozen others that would be much easier to handle.

Comment: What @agentp said.  But maybe you can get what you want with `CForm` plus a few supporting definitions, e.g., `def List(*x): return list(x)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data from Mathematica import to Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173958/data-from-mathematica-import-to-python)

Answer (score 0):

example of complex number exchange:

mathematica:

```
  Export["cmplx.csv",RandomComplex[{-1-I,1+I} , {3,3}]
```

python:

```
  import csv
  reader=csv.reader(open('cmplx.csv','r'))
  complexarray=[complex(item.replace('*I','j'))
        for row in reader for item in row]
```

This is suitable really for small amounts of data. For large arrays I'd split off the real and imaginary parts to separate arrays , use the binary exchange shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184067/1004168 and reassemble to complex with numpy.

mathematica:

```
m = Table[RandomComplex[], {3}, {3}]
f = OpenWrite["test.bin", BinaryFormat -> True];
BinaryWrite[f, ArrayDepth[m], "Integer32"];
BinaryWrite[f, Dimensions[m], "Integer32"];
BinaryWrite[f, Re[m], "Real64"];
BinaryWrite[f, Im[m], "Real64"];
Close[f]
```

python:

```
import numpy as np
with open('test.bin','rb') as f:
 depth=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('int32'),count=1)
 dims=np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('int32'),count=depth)
 count=reduce(lambda x,y:x*y,dims)
 complexarray=np.reshape(np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('float64'),
    count=count),dims)   
 complexarray=complexarray+
    1j*np.reshape(np.fromfile(f,dtype=np.dtype('float64'),
    count=count),dims)
```